# How to get Pygame script to run on macOS

Tags: python, macos, pygame

I have a rather small Pygame based python script and I just bought a Mac so I'm trying to run my script on here. Everything has been installed correctly (Checking by typing 'import Pygame') into python terminal as-well as running a basic hello world program. However, when I try running this script, IDLE gets brought to the front but nothing happens from there. (The script is supposed to pop-up a new window). Is this a problem with my installations or my code? (Code works on windows setup).

Comment: try running it outside of idle

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: Like `python3 file.py` in terminal

Comment: It gives me a no such file or directory error

Comment: Make sure to do the full filepath

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: Running through terminal worked

Comment: that is good to know

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run the script again on a windows computer to see if you forgot to save some changes or if the file got corrupted somehow. You could also use bootcamp to install Windows on your mac since you could have one windows version on your mac for coding purposes and the regular mac OS for other stuff if you like.

Answer (score 0):

you can execute it by left clicking in your script and select open with python launcher